# What is the redirect URI for Microsoft OneDrive?

Tags: oauth-2.0, onedrive

I want to use OAuth2 in Microsoft OneDrive. The application is Windows and Android, but I don't know what should I insert in redirect uri. I will be grateful if anyone helps me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you're new here, I recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips. Your question is lacking sufficient detail to help the community help you. Please be more specific about your environment, your scenario and what code/samples you're using.

Answer (score 1):

This is specified in Microsoft's documentation for the OneDrive REST API: "OneDrive authentication and sign-in"

> Use this redirect URL for mobile and desktop applications `https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/msa-oauth

Answer (score 0):

As of Jan 24 2022

> Register your app The first step is to register an app with Microsoft
> and provide some details about your app. You can register your
> application and receive a new app ID from the Azure App registrations page: https://aka.ms/AppRegistrations

Then click on Authentication on the left menu